# How do you enable customers use their openid on your website, just like stackoverflow?

Tags: php, mysql, openid

I want customers to use their openId on my site. I googled for this but didn't find any good tutorial. I use PHP and MySQL.

There is one at Plaxo. But it says we should download something from JanRain.com.

I saw the openId module of Drupal. It doesn't want anything to be downloaded.

Can anyone tell me what to do exactly?

Comment: +1 for opening up a very interesting topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many decent libraries are listed here:
http://wiki.openid.net/Libraries

Comment: Examples on this link are no longer active :|

Answer (score 24):

Stack Overflow uses this library for the smoking hot javascript interface: http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/

Comment: You can see the code they're using at http://sstatic.net/so/Js/third-party/openid-jquery.js

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I (and probably the OP) was looking for. For some reason it is really hard to find.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal's OpenID module [started off using the JanRain library in 4.7.x](http://drupal.org/project/openid), which is the most commonly used implementation of OpenID in PHP.

You don't have to download a library in Drupal because it's already built into Drupal core.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [rpx](http://rpxnow.com) like [uservoice](http://uservoice.com/login) does.

Answer (score 3):

If you are hosting your site on a linux machine, there should be a php-openid package you can install that will supply you with an open id client library you can use to enable open id logins.  The package comes with good example code to get you started.  If you aren't running linux or your distribution doesn't have php-openid, I'm 99% certain that php-openid is based on (or is directly) JanRain.com's php library, so downloading it directly should get you the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework has also developed an [OpenID Component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.html) that can be used as a standalone (i.e. not dependent upon the rest of the framework), or, at the very least, requires minimal interaction (I believe it uses a responce object for redirection).

Either way, it's Yet Another Option, and especially usefull if building a ZF backed site.

Answer (score 1):

The following libraries are available to assist with the implementation of an OpenID Identity Server and Consumer in PHP. The libraries in this section are intended to help with handling all of the details specific to OpenID and leaving you to provide the glue to integrate it into your site. <sup>([source](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries))</sup>

- [LightOpenID](https://github.com/iignatov/LightOpenID)
  An PHP 5 library for easy openid authentication. Works only as a consumer.
  License: [MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
- [PEAR OpenID library](http://pear.php.net/package/OpenID/)
  PHP 5 consumer OpenID library.
  License: [BSD](http://www.linfo.org/bsdlicense.html)
- [PHP OpenID Library](http://www.openidenabled.com/php-openid/) (Janrain)
  The PHP OpenID library lets you enable OpenID authentication on sites built using PHP. It features the OpenID consumer, Store implementations, and an OpenID server.
  License: [Apache v2](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)
- [Simple OpenID PHP Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3290.html)
  Authenticate users with OpenID single sign-on
  License: Unknown
- [OpenID component for CakePHP](http://code.42dh.com/openid/)
  An OpenID component for CakeP
  License: [MIT](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
- [sfOpenIDPlugin for Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfOpenIDPlugin)
  Module to handle authentication via OpenID
  License: Unknown
- [EasyOpenID](http://www.codymays.net/content/2007/02/20/the-future-and-openid/)
  A PEAR-free library for OpenID relying party.
  License: BSD/GPL
- [NetMesh InfoGrid LID](http://infogrid.org/trac/wiki/LID) (not available for download?!)
  License: [Sleepycat](https://opensource.org/licenses/Sleepycat)
- [Zend Framework OpenID Component](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendOpenId)
  Zend_OpenId is a Zend Framework component that provides a simple API for building OpenID-enabled sites and identity providers.
  License: [BSD](http://www.linfo.org/bsdlicense.html)

Answer (score 0):

I only glanced at it, but does http://www.saeven.net/openid.htm do the trick for you?

Answer (score 0):

[HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html) is an open source social sign on php library.

The main goal of HybridAuth library is to act as an abstract api between your application and various social apis and identities providers such as Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google and Yahoo.

HybridAuth enable developers to easily build social applications to engage websites vistors and customers on a social level by implementing social signin, social sharing, users profiles, friends list, activities stream, status updates and more.

Hello world with HybridAuth:

```
<?php
 $config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/library/config.php';
 require_once( "library/Hybrid/Auth.php" );

 try{
     $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config ); 
     $twitter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Twitter" );
     $user_profile = $twitter->getUserProfile();
     echo "Hi there! " . $user_profile->displayName;
     $twitter->setUserStatus( "Hello world!" );
     $user_contacts = $twitter->getUserContacts();
 }
 catch( Exception $e ){
     echo "Ooophs, we got an error: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
```