# how to implement signup mechanism in open id

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

i am using dot net open id for implementing openid in my website i want to redirect user to any of the open id provider site for sign up just like that of stack overflow provides for myopenid how to achieve this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you enable customers use their openid on your website, just like stackoverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477144/how-do-you-enable-customers-use-their-openid-on-your-website-just-like-stackover)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477144/how-do-you-enable-customers-use-their-openid-on-your-website-just-like-stackover) and then go snag [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.DotNetOpenAuth.net) as your server library.

Comment: no no its not like that what i want is signup mechanism not sign in i have implemented the sign-in mechanism and it is working fine.
for example in stackoverflow they provide a link to myopenid site on clicking of which an affiliate id comes in url and user redirected to their site after signing up there user comes back to stackoverflow as a new user

Comment: So it's the UI from StackOverflow you want to capture, including the buttons and the way you can sign up as a new user and still log into the original site?  That's all part of the openid selector jscript control that they're using that's discussed in the answers of the question I linked to.  And as for redirecting the user back after sign-up, that's standard (decent) OpenID Provider behavior.