# Embed yahoo,google and fb login on my site

Tags: facebook, google-signin

I am thinking of embedding different login methods for my website, like login through google account, facebook account and yahoo account.

What do i need to do for that ??

I don't know anything about auto-login.

Any link or explanation to the question will do work...

Thanks :)

Comment: See info about the API's provided by Google (http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) and Facebook (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this and many others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235735/how-to-add-social-login-services-from-google-facebook-yahoo-etc-to-my-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID).

Answer (score 0):

You you need is API . 
for example let say, you are letting user to login with Facebook id, then you need to create  page in facebook ... so after then you get API . then configure it.

If you have zero knowledge in such thing , it'll be tough task