# how to remember user without registration

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, session-cookies

I want users to be remembered on my site but I don't have any kind of signup. I want user to choose a username when he comes to the website for the first time and then for every other request from that user I want to remember the username. I tried this-

As a user can't signup using Facebook or email or anything else, I was not able to find a way to remember user. So, I mapped the user's username with his `IP` Address and saved it to the database. So, subsequent requests from that `IP` Address would tell me 'which user it is'. But then I came to know that `IP` Address can change when you reset your modem/connection. And for static `IP` Address you have to pay your `ISP`. Then, I am quite sure that most of the users have dynamic `IP` Addresses.

So, is there a way to do this? I know about `cookies` and `sessions` but I don't think that's the best way. May be I am wrong. I just want to know how big players in the world tackle this type of problem. Or maybe, what better solutions are out there to do this? Please give me directions.

**Added:**

As based on an answer, if I do it on basis of cookies, won't that delete user history when the cookies are removed from the browser? And if the user login in from same PC using different browsers, won't he be asked username multiple times?

Comment: use cookies or session, that will accomplish your job

Comment: So you don't want to use OAuth, cookies, or even IPs. Have you considered using [Data Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)? Or maybe even [Flash Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object), as they separate from the browser and require an extra step to remove.

Comment: Cookies and localStorage will be lost when the user clears personal data or changes browser. The only throughout solution I know to "remember" user is registration - you can use OAuth to facilitate registration (e.g. creating account without having to fill a form).

Comment: @DaveChen I think the only solution left is to get an email.

Comment: Forgive me for being forward about this, but it's honestly just two text fields, **username** & **password**, if your users can't type into **two** text fields, then maybe they don't value their participation as a user on your site. A website should make their users want to register on it.

Comment: Got that sir, but the site is actually kind of a chatting site with no need of user identity. That was the reason for trying to escape all that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't rely on IP addresses. Use an infinite cookie. In jQuery you can set a cookie to expire as follows (showing 20 years expiration - that should be enough!):

```
$.cookie('my_cookie', 'my_value', { expires: 365 * 20 });
```

If you're worried about the user clearing cookies, another interesting approach is to ask for an email address (just email, no password). Then you can email that user a link back to your site with an access token appended to the URL which authenticates that user - and store it again in an infinite cookie. This way, you always have a way of authenticating a user without requiring formal sign up.

EDIT: Reading your question again it looks like you're trying to remember a user's account based solely on what the user tells you his username is. This is not a secure approach and also will result in lost accounts. You're going to need to save something on the server, whether a unique token, password, or email address.

Comment: Amm.. Won't that delete user history when the cookies are removed from the browser? And if the user login in from same PC using different browser, won't he be asked username two times?

Comment: Yes - in that case just ask for the email address and email an access token as described above.

Comment: How is that not secure and will result in lost account?

Comment: @user1708762 How is the server supposed to know who is who? If the user is using a different computer/browser the server is going to ask for their credentials again. You should respect your users by respecting their privacy by making sure they authenticate properly to your website.

Comment: @DaveChen I am asking for a way because usually people want to escape emails and pwds. And another reason for asking is to know whether a better way exists out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any kind of login, there is no concrete way to remember the visiting user, here is why :

**Cookies :** i clear my cache, or use different browser to access the site, then, cookie logic would fail ( *cookies are also browser specific* )

**Session :** Browser is closed for sufficient time and session might get destroyed

**IP :** change of machine / location / modem( *on same machine as last time* ) will change the IP

One simple work around for this problem is to use  [**open-id**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) for login, this way, u wont have to worry about the credentials and this will offer a secure way to.

Check this thread on how to use open-id to embedd to a site : **[How to add Social login services from Google, Facebook, Yahoo etc. to my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235735/how-to-add-social-login-services-from-google-facebook-yahoo-etc-to-my-website)**